# Прокрутка ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, прокрутка

Добрый день друзья)
Кто мне подскажет как такую прокрутку можно реализовать? и как сделать вывод именно 6 элементов листвью. Буду очень признателен за помощь)

[image]

Comment: Почитай про  
 View Holder

Comment: Нда, как напридумают дизайнеры, потом прогеры и мучаются :) Сочувствую...